# Как добавить одну запись поля формы в несколько моделей

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Есть таблица законов `tbl_law`. Есть две другие таблицы: категории `tbl_cat` и группы `tbl_group`. Закон может состоять как в нескольких категориях так и в нескольких группах, и наоборот у одной категории или группы могут быть несколько законов (многие ко многим).

Мне нужно сделать след. форму для заполнения:

1. `id` закона
2. `id` категории
3. `id` группы

При этом `id` категории добавляется в связующую таблицу `tbl_cat_law`, а id группы добавляется в связующую таблицу `tbl_group_law`.

Получается, что `id` закона должен добавиться сразу в две модели данных (модели связующих таблиц `tbl_cat_law` и `tbl_group_law`). Как это сделать на `YII`?

Спасибо добрым людям.

Answer (score 3):

Итак предложу решение в лоб  имеем  3  таблицы и 2 связующие ( `tbl_cat_law  tbl_group_law`) Получаем данные с формы и в  методе отправляем эти данные сначала в 1 связующую потом 2 во вторую просто передавая нужные данные в каждую  модель. Ну а дальше я думаю понятно. Пардон но как то без примера.

Answer (score 0):

Визуализация ответа [@Flur](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/12580/flur) (Пример: связывание `tbl_law` и `tbl_cat`)

Создаем таблицу `tbl_cat_law` всего с тремя полями: `id (Primary key)`, `cat_id (foreign_key: tbl_law.law_id [ON UPDATE и ON DELETE - CASCADE])`, `law_id (foreign_key: tbl_cat.law_id [ON UPDATE и ON DELETE - CASCADE])`.
В результате имеем таблицу со сявязками закон-категория, записи из которой изменяются/удаляются при смене/удалении закона или категории

```
class Law extends CActiveRecord{
  //...
  public functions relations(){
    'cat' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Cat', 'tbl_cat_law(law_id, cat_id)'), 
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

Далее используем связь как и все остальные связи: `Law::model()->with('cat')->findAll();`